# How to preserve state in flutter `DataTable()2`

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a `DataTable2()` which is used to display almost 200 data. I read in flutter official document that it is costly to use `DataTable()`. Is it bad for using 200 data ?
Another problem for me is i am being unable to preserve `state` . i have used `PageStorage()` but it only preserve `state` if user scrolls, else it doesn't work. By that i mean if a user scrolls to the 3rd row and navigate to another screen and come back to the page it preserves the `state` but if the user again navigates to another page without scrolling the `DataTable2()` it doesn't preserve the `state`

```
PageStorage(
                  bucket: bucketGlobalForViewStudent,
                  child: DataTable2(
                    key: const PageStorageKey<String>("ViewStudent"),
                    scrollController: _controller,
                    showCheckboxColumn: false,
                    horizontalScrollController: _horizontalController,
                    isVerticalScrollBarVisible: true,
                    isHorizontalScrollBarVisible: true,
                    sortArrowIcon: Icons.keyboard_arrow_up, 
                    showBottomBorder: true,
                    sortArrowAnimationDuration:
                        const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                    columnSpacing: 0,
                    horizontalMargin: 12,
                    bottomMargin: 10,
                    minWidth: 600,
                    columns: _createColumns(),
                    rows: _createRows(),
                    sortColumnIndex: _currentSortColumn,
                    sortAscending: _isAscending.value,
                    headingRowHeight: 45,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
                    ),
                    dataRowHeight: 40,
                    dividerThickness: 1,
                  ),
                ),
```

Thanks